# Snowflake regexp_substr with out pattern in result

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake I try to get the first occurrence of the values between -> and -> in a column

I use regexp_substr with the following code, which return `->ABCD->` and not just `ABCD`

```
select regexp_substr('98547279->ABCD->2554785->DEFT', '->[[:alnum:]\-]+->') AS "SUBSTRING";
```

How can I prevent to get the -> -> in the result?

Answer (score 1):

Try it [with a group](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html#examples) `()`

```
select regexp_substr('98547279->ABCD->2554785->DEFT',
                     '->([[:alnum:]\-]+)(->|$)', 1, 1, 'e', 1) AS "SUBSTRING"
```

Comment: It works thx. 

If I have this case '98547279->ABCD' where it is only one `->` is it then possible to have some kind OR ? so if only one -> then rest of the string to the right else between -> and ->

Comment: Changed the regex.  `(->|$)`   So either the `->` or the end of the string `$`

Answer (score 1):

If regexp is not a must, then [SPLIT_PART](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html) does the job:

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART('98547279->ABCD->2554785->DEFT', '->', 1) AS result
-- ABCD
```